# I just want to change the URL on Runtime?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am having anchor tag referring to a url i.e

```
<a taget='_blank' href='http://localhost:4850/en/abc.xml'>
```

I just want on runtime after clicking on this hyperlink the website will go to

```
http://localhost:4850/abc.xml
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:4850/en/abc.xml
```

i.e the "en" from the url is removed.

I am having a .Net Application

Comment: how is `href` set? is it under your control or is rendered by something?

Comment: try this $('selector').attr('href','your new HREF');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that your anchor tag with `id` is like

```
<a taget='_blank' id="url" href='http://localhost:4850/en/abc.xml'>
```

Using javascript, on clicking your anchor tag

```
$('#url').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location.href = 'http://localhost:4850/abc.xml';
});
```

It will redirect you to respected url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Your anchor tag is like this:-

```
<a taget='_blank' href='http://localhost:4850/en/abc.xml' id="anc1">Test</a>
```

Use this script

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("a[ID$='anc1']").click(function () {
                    var url = $(this).attr("href");
                    var newurl = url.replace("/en", "");
                    $(this).attr("href", newurl);
                });
             });
           </script>
```